# Recognizing what JSP called the Servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have two JSP pages that can access a Servlet. Now, I want when JSP 1 access the Servlet, Servlet will do some one kind of job (for example increment an int) and when JSP 2 will access the Servlet, it will do some other kind of job (for example decrement an int).

Can anybody help me by specifying how is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass different value on same parameter.

In page1.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="/MyServelt">
   <jsp:param name="action" value="incr" /> 
</jsp:forward/>
```

In page2.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="/MyServelt">
   <jsp:param name="action" value="decr" /> 
</jsp:forward/>
```

If `<form>` tag is used then add `<input type="hidden"/>`,

```
<form method="post" action="/MyServlet">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="incr"/>
  .....
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using <form ACTION="Servlet">  </form> tag to invoke servlet. But, it says <jsp:param name="action" value="decr" /> can't be used in that. Any procedure to solve it ? Sorry, I have very few knowledge about servlet & jsp.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ***Servlets are not page***.

Second, solution to your problem will be to pass a parameter in request from jsp page to servlet that helps in identifying from where the request has been made and by using this parameter decide which operation you should do or you can also use `referer` header of request or `getRequestURI()` method of request to get it but I have never used it so not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

use synchronous keyword to the method that does the increment or decrement operation.

This is more like isolation in database transaction. Secondly to decide what exactly to do,

You can use the request parameters eg - domain/myservlet?action=increment

:)